# Flask-cache generate different keys for int and long parameters

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-cache

Flask-cache use function parameters to generate cache key, however it makes different keys for long and int type parameters:

```
@cache.memoize(3600)
def foo(a):
    return a
```

`foo(1)` and `foo(1L)` will generate different cache keys, what could I do to assign their return value to a same cache key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert integer number to long by subclass.

eg.

```
class CustomCache(Cache):
    def _memoize_kwargs_to_args(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        keyargs, keykwargs = super(CardCache, self) \
            ._memoize_kwargs_to_args(f, *args, **kwargs)

        new_args = []
        for arg in keyargs:
            if isinstance(arg, numbers.Integral):
                arg = long(arg)
            new_args.append(arg)

        return tuple(new_args), keykwargs
```